# Why is Bootstrap modal receiving focus on tab?

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, accessibility

The [React Bootstrap modal](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) has a tabIndex of -1, yet it can be tabbed into and focused upon:

`<div role="dialog" aria-modal="true" class="fade modal show" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; padding-right: 0px;">`

Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-johnson-y6z2e?file=/src/App.js

The modal will have a big blue box around it when in focus.

In my project, I have a modal window with two buttons on it. I need to be able to tab back and forth between the buttons (without using shift-tab). When I hit tab for the third time, it focuses on the modal, leaving no focused button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because elements with `tabindex="-1"` can still receive programatic focus.

> A negative value (usually tabindex="-1") means that the element is not
> reachable via sequential keyboard navigation, but could be focused
> with Javascript or visually by clicking with the mouse. It's mostly
> useful to create accessible widgets with JavaScript.
> [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Under the hood, Bootstrap controls focus so that when you open a modal, focus is placed on the modal, and when closed, it returns focus to the previously focused element.

It also traps focus - which, in your example, is why you can't to use `shift` + `tab` to move "backwards" from the modal.

You can adjust this behavior by setting the `autoFocus` flag to `false`.

```
<Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} autoFocus={false}>
  ...
</Modal>
```

Note that setting `autoFocus` to `false` is generally considered bad practice as it makes the modal less accessible.

^ I think this answers the title of your question, though I think what you're trying to achieve is actually unrelated. If you want to move focus from "button 2" to "button 1" when pressing `tab` you'll have to do so programatically. Maybe something like...

```
const btnRef = React.useRef();

const handleTab = () => {
  btnRef.current.focus();
}


return (
  <>
    ...
    <Button ref={btnRef}>
      Close
    </Button>
    <Button onBlur={handleTab}>
      Save Changes
    </Button>
    ...
  </>
)
```